# Push notification data when app is not running?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When the app is not running and user receives, say 5 push notifications, are those push notifications saved somewhere? Or is that data gone? I need to access all 5 push notifications when the app runs the next time.

To clarify, I already understand that you can access the push notification that caused the app to run. What I'm asking is to get all push notifications since the app got terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The APNS service will only retain the most recent pushed message to a device - assuming there is still at least one other app installed AND the user allows push notifications for it, then this one stored message will be delivered the next time the user has an Internet connection.

For better information on the quality of service that Apple has implemented for the APNS service, see my other answer here:

[Clarification on Apple APNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104935/clarification-on-apple-apns/12213704#12213704)